# Multiple HTTP.Redirect Options with Azure Function?

Tags: c#, url, azure-functions, http-redirect

i'm new to programming and therefore need some help developing an Azure Function and hope you can help me.

What needs to happen in the Azure Function is that i have multiple URLs i want to be able to redirect to, depending on the input I give to the Function. There will be more than 100 options i need to add. But for the question it's enough if i make an example with 5 options.

For Example:

1. Input "A" = Redirect to LinkedIn,
2. Input "B" = Redirect to Xing,
3. Input "C" = Redirect to Power Automate,
4. Input "D" = Rdirect to Power Apps,
5. Input "null" = Redirect to Google,

I tried a few things out but didn't have any success sadly.

My two questions would be:

1. Is it possible to do something like that with a single Azure Function?
2. How could an example code of this Program look like?

Thanks in Advance